# Objective C: How to highlight the first cell in table view when view loads?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, highlight

I am trying to default the top cell in my table view to be highlighted whenever the subview appears.

I tried to do this:

```
switch(indexPath.row) { // assuming there is only one section
    case 0:
      cell.textLabel.text = @"First Cell:";
      cell.highlighted = YES
      break;
```

But this doesn't work as I get a black overlay on my first cell instead.

EDIT (added screenshot)

[image]

Any advise on this will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Zhen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you need is,

```
cell.selected = YES;
```

If you want it animated you can use,

```
[cell setSelected:YES animated:YES];
```

Comment: thanks for your response. Yup I tried that too, with the same result. I have attached the screenshot in my original post

Comment: @Zhen: You have set any bg color for cell.textLabel?

Comment: nope, all I did was to set the textColor. Everything else is as per default

Comment: @Zhen: Sorry man.. This looks strange to me.. May be someone else will help you..

Answer (score 4):

I had the exact same problem. You need to move your code into willDisplayCell, instead of cellForRowAtIndexPath.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if(indexPath.row == 0) {

        [cell setSelected:YES animated:NO];
    }
}
```